# Using cmd-N and cmd-T with emacs

Tags: init-file, buffers, osx, tabs

I am using a Mac 10.9.5 and Emacs 24.4, installed with macports and aliased as

```
alias emacs  /Applications/MacPorts/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs
```

At the moment, when I have an emacs file open and I hit `Cmd-N`, emacs opens a replicate of the file already open. I am wondering if there is a way to modify the .emacs file so I can open new, Untitled empty files by using `Cmd-N`, like when using Aquamacs or MacVim.

In addition, when using aquamacs or MacVim, `Cmd-T` opens a new, Untitled tab next to the already existing (see screen capture attached[image]).

In my emacs window, `cmd-T` opens the font menu. Is there a way to get `cmd-T` to behave in Emacs as in MacVim or aquamacs?

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: Please do some background research before posting.  A quick google search for "Emacs keybindings" gives you the [manual page](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Key-Bindings.html) and [Mickey's nice tutorial](http://www.masteringemacs.org/article/mastering-key-bindings-emacs) among the first hits.  You may also like [Xah Lee's tutorial](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/keyboard_shortcuts.html), which has a portion about Mac keybindings as well.

Comment: Hi Dan. Thanks for the reply. My apologies if the question is so trivial. I did try a few things before but they did not work, although I did not know about http://www.masteringemacs.org/article/mastering-key-bindings-emacs . Thanks again.

Comment: it's okay since you're just starting and learning how this place works.  As a general rule, it's best to do some background research to the best of your ability and, once you get stuck, post a question (but let us know what you've tried so far!).  I doubt anyone will fault you for being new provided that you put a good-faith effort into solving your problem ahead of posting.

Comment: thanks. For example, I just tried this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25791605/emacs-how-do-i-create-a-new-empty-buffer-whenever-creating-a-new-frame and it did work. However, so far I have not found the `cmd-T` equivalent. Surely I'll find it soon. Thanks again :)

Comment: On Mac, the command key is understood by emacs as the 'super' key.  Thus, command-t would be `(kbd "s-t")`.

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks. Based on http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_hyper_super_keys.html I have actually included the following 3lines in my .emacs file: `(setq mac-command-modifier 'meta) ;; make cmd key do Meta (setq mac-option-modifier 'super) ;; make opt key do Super
(setq mac-control-modifier 'control) ;; make Control key do Control`. Then `(global-set-key (kbd "s-t") 'switch-to-buffer)` but does not seem to work. Is this correct?

Comment: BTW, including only `(global-set-key (kbd "s-t") 'switch-to-buffer)` creates a new buffer when using cmd-T, but what I want is the new buffer to be display like in the picture shown above (if possible, of course), like when you use MacVim. Nevermind Sean, is all right, I can live without this feature. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Is it possible you're thinking of tabbar-mode which comes pre-installed in Aquamacs, but needs to be installed in the generic version of Emacs?  Here is a link to the Github source code for Tabbar:  https://github.com/dholm/tabbar  I use tabbar.el all by itself without the Aquamacs *improvements*.

Comment: THANK YOU lawlist, tabbar is exactly what I was thinking. Thanks!

Comment: Everything works perfectly, thanks again. All problems solved :)

Comment: Then I suggest you write a short answer yourself and accept it afterwards. That way, this question will not remain listed as unanswered, which is a bit annoying.